# Why doesn't inequality hold as a property in natural number induction?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, peano-axioms

It is said that all natural numbers follow the rule of induction: if a said property holds for one number and for its successor, it holds for all natural numbers.

But, let us define the following property: n < 10

It holds for 1, as 1<10, and it holds for 2, as 2<10.

But it clearly does not hold for all natural numbers.

I believe it is quite unlikely I've proven Peano Arithmetic wrong, so could somebody point the error in my reasoning?

Comment: $n<10$ holds for 9 but fails for 10.

Comment: You are using a misleading formulation. The induction principle holds if a property holds for one number n_0, and if the implication (it holds for n $\Rightarrow$ it holds for $n+1$) is valid. It is not sufficient if it holds for $n_0$ and $n_0 + 1$.

Comment: Nailed it, Thomas!

Comment: When you're stating that $n\lt 10$, note that you've a fixed upper bound which is independent of $n$. Induction doesn't work for inequalities with fixed bounds since you've restricted the domain of the inequality.

Comment: Think for a second: it would mean that any property that holds for two successive naturals would be true for all. Like $2$ and $3$ are prime numbers, so all naturals are prime !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct statement is "if said property holds for some number then it holds for its successor".

In this case, $\color{red}{n<10\implies n+1<10}$, which is clearly false for $n=9$.

A correct example could be with the property $n>10$.

Indeed, $\color{green}{n>10\implies n+1>11\implies n+1>10}$.

Also note that the property must be established independently for some value called the base case. In the second example, the base case could be $n=11$, and the the property is established for all $n\ge11$.

Answer (score 2):

If $9<10$ does it follow that $10<10$?

Answer (score 1):

Induction is founded on a base case (true for $1$ or $0$ - definitions differ a little, but it doesn't matter in the end), and a case concerned with the successor function - that if the statement is true for $n$ it is also true for $n+1$ however large $n$ is.

Now $n+1\lt x$ is only true when $n\lt x-1$, so $n\lt x$ is not strong enough to establish the successor part of the induction for all $n$.